# How to fix a corrupted project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I don't know what happened with my Delphi.
It doesn't respond to my requests:

1. when I Search for a certain word it leads me to wrong places.
2. when I ctrl-click a certain function or variable it does nothing.
3. when I click on an event from the Design it doesn't take me to the right function.
4. Upon tracing, it stops without a rational reason.

This happens only with this project, because I opened a new project and it acted fine.
Is there something corrupted with this project? (It is compiled and being built without errors.)

Comment: something is out of sync in your project. delete all projects' *.dcus, reload and rebuild project.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what is .dsk? I don't have .dsk file

Comment: No need to delete it. Did you try creating a brand new project from revision control, from a time when you had no problems.

Comment: I removed .dcus and still mal functioning

Comment: Can you provide more details (Excerpt or files attachement) related to your "this project" ? (

Comment: I took this project at work from the server, then compiled it and started working with, from the first day it wasn't fine. Does this have any relation? It doesn't have file attachements or something like that. It is a normal project with more than one form and units.

Comment: Delete or move into another folder the <YourProjectName>.dproj and launch it again with <YourProjectName>.dpr (You may have to fix some project settings usually persisted in the file after its rebuilding by default).

Comment: Didn't work either. Actually I noticed that some units are working fine, would the problem be in some units or forms?

Comment: Check those units which "doesn't work" with some hex editor to see do they have correct line end symbols (#13#10). The Delphi IDE shows file OK when it has ie linux lineends but some of the functionality is messed up then just as you experience...

Comment: Zip the broken project, make it available as file attachement so as people willing to answer can reproduce the issues you reported.

Comment: This could happen when there are invalid characters as @ain mentioned. I have also seen strange behavior when using complex `with` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this happens with a particular unit, it could be because you have a PAS file with corrupted line ends or some Unicode problem.

The usual, easy to spot symptom is that the blue dots on the compiled lines are out of sync with the actual code. (only the line where the debugger should be able to stop have the blue dots).

The simplest remedy is to copy the whole unit and paste it into a plain Notepad, then a quick scan for goofy characters will tell you if there is a possible unicode glitch. Once this is ruled out, just copy again the whole text and paste it back into the IDE; this should fix all the non-Windows line ends.

For the anecdote, it used to happen a lot where I was working when we had outsourcing with guys using Cyrillic based editors...

Comment: +1. The easier fix, though, is just to open the .pas file in Notepad, make a dummy change (add a blank line and then remove it), and save the file. Notepad will automatically fix the mismatched CR/LF pairs when it saves, and you don't have to go to the trouble of copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Start a new project (keep a backup of your old one!)
2. copy over the content of your current `.dpr` file, but not the `uses` part.
3. Then unit for unit start importing the units from your old project
   Perform all your actions at this stage (for each unit you try) to see for which unit it fails

Then compare your `.dproj` file with your old `.dproj` file, and mention the differences in a comment to see if we can resolve those differences.